# Making a new command for tabular environments with flexible table sizes

Tags: tables, macros

I'm trying to create essentially a "new command" or "new environment" with a tabular environment. Is there any possibility to make a simple command that allows me to enter the size of the table and its corresponding entries. For instance, I want to make a command that makes the first table and just change a few numbers to create the second table. How would I accomplish this? Please let me know and thank you.

```
\begin{document} 
\[
    \begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}|*{8}{>{$}c<{$}}}
    & E   & 2A   & B & 2C & 2D\\
    \hline
    \vrule height 12pt width 0pt
    \Gamma_1  &  (1)  &  (1)  & (1) & (1) & (1)\\
    \Gamma_2   & 1  & (1) & 1  & -1 &-1 \\
    \Gamma_3 & 1 & -1   & 1 & 1 & -1\\
    \Gamma_4   & 1   & -1  & 1  & (-1) & 1\\
    \Gamma_5 & (2) & 0 & (-2) & 0 & 0\\
    \end{tabular}
\]
\[
    \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}|*{8}{>{$}l<{$}}}
    C_{3\si{v}}   & E   & C_3   & C_3^2 & \sv & \sv' & \sv'' \\
    \hline
    \vrule height 12pt width 0pt
    E  & E   & C_3   & C_3^2 & \sv & \sv' & \sv'' \\
    C_3   & C_3   & C_3^2 & E  & \sv'' & \sv & \sv' \\
    C_3^2 & C_3^2 & E   & C_3  & \sv' & \sv'' & \sv\\
    \sv   & \sv   & \sv'  & \sv''  & E & C_3 & C_3^2\\
    \sv' & \sv' & \sv'' & \sv & C_3^2 & E & C_3\\
    \sv'' & \sv'' & \sv & \sv' & C_3 &C_3^2 & E\\
    \end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How are `\si` and `\sv` defined?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you explained what you mean by "just change a few numbers". The first `tabular` has 5 (not 8) data columns and 5 data rows, whereas the second `tabular` has 6 each. Are you looking for an algorithmic way to go from a 5x5 to a 6x6 table?

Comment: Oh sorry, \si is from a siunitx package. And the \sv is defined as \sigma_{v}.

Comment: To clarify my initial post, I wanted to basically type 5 or 6 or any number to set the size of the table like 5x5 or 6x6. Then input like a list of numbers or letters to fill the table. If that helps.

Comment: I suppose it might be useful to create a macro called, say, `\Tstrut` -- e.g., `\newcommand\Tstrut{\vrule height 12pt width 0pt}` -- to simplify inputting a "top strut".

Comment: If it's a matter of `\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}|*{8}{>{$}c<{$}}}` being tedious to type, I would suggest you switch from `tabular` (which is meant to be use for (mostly) text material to `array`, which is designed for math material. E.g., given that the first table has 5 (not 8) data columns, you might write  `\begin{array}{c|*{5}{c}}`. A lot tidier, right? (Of course, you would also have to replace `\end{tabular}` with `\end{array}`...) Relative to making this (somewhat obvious) change, I don't think there's much to be gained from creating a "wrapper macro" around the `array` environment.

Comment: you should be using array here not tabular oter than that it really isn't clear what you want to change. The columns in your array are just being set to their natural width so you don't need to specify any sizes.

Comment: please edit your example so that it may be run, it is missing a documentclass and the packages and definitions you mentioned in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to define an environment for structures that are repeated more than twice in a document.

You should use `array` and not `tabular`, but that's essentially all. Find a better name than `foo`. The optional argument is for the alignment in the columns, default `c`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newcommand{\sv}{\sigma_{v}}
\newcommand{\rowstrut}{\rule{0pt}{12pt}}

\newenvironment{foo}[2][c]
 {\begin{array}{#1|*{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{#1}}#2\\\hline\rowstrut}
 {\end{array}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{foo}{& E & 2A & B & 2C & 2D}
  \Gamma_1 & (1) & (1) & (1)  & (1)  & (1) \\
  \Gamma_2 & 1   & (1) & 1    & -1   & -1  \\
  \Gamma_3 & 1   & -1  & 1    & 1    & -1  \\
  \Gamma_4 & 1   & -1  & 1    & (-1) & 1   \\
  \Gamma_5 & (2) & 0   & (-2) & 0    & 0   \\
\end{foo}
\]
\[
\begin{foo}[l]{C_{3v} & E & C_3 & C_3^2 & \sv & \sv' & \sv''}
  E     & E     & C_3   & C_3^2 & \sv   & \sv'  & \sv'' \\
  C_3   & C_3   & C_3^2 & E     & \sv'' & \sv   & \sv'  \\
  C_3^2 & C_3^2 & E     & C_3   & \sv'  & \sv'' & \sv   \\
  \sv   & \sv   & \sv'  & \sv'' & E     & C_3   & C_3^2 \\
  \sv'  & \sv'  & \sv'' & \sv   & C_3^2 & E     & C_3   \\
  \sv'' & \sv'' & \sv   & \sv'  & C_3   & C_3^2 & E     \\
\end{foo}
\]

\end{document}
```

I used `MaxMatrixCols` that's the same counter used for matrices in `amsmath`. You can use `*{20}{c}` as well.

[image]

I removed `\si{v}` as there is no unit with symbol “v” and every other ‘v’ in the table is in math italic.